# Cassandra Too Many Open Files . Port died

Tags: unix, cassandra, nosql

one of the Cassandra 2.0 node crashed  with "TOO many open files" message. currently we have set nofile limit to 32768 as specified in http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/install/recommended_settings.

As we are still seeing the error should we increase it more? what is the production recommended value? any side effects of increase this nofile limit? what causes the open files to grow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at an old document.  The current doc (for version 2.x) from DataStax [Recommended Production Settings](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html) indicates that the `nofile` value should be set to 100,000.

> Packaged installs: Ensure that the following settings are included in
>   the /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf file:
>
> ```
> cassandra - memlock unlimited
> cassandra - nofile 100000
> cassandra - nproc 32768
> cassandra - as unlimited
> ```
>
> Tarball installs: Ensure that the following settings are included in the /etc/security/limits.conf file:
>
> ```
> * - memlock unlimited
> * - nofile 100000
> * - nproc 32768
> * - as unlimited
> ```
>
> If you run Cassandra as root, some Linux distributions such as Ubuntu, require setting the limits for root explicitly instead of using *:
>
> ```
> root - memlock unlimited
> root - nofile 100000
> root - nproc 32768
> root - as unlimited
> ```

Try that, and see if it helps.

Comment: I made the changes in /etc/security/limits.conf as below            * - memlock unlimited
* - nofile 100000
* - nproc 32768
* - as unlimited
root - memlock unlimited
root - nofile 100000
root - nproc 32768
root - as unlimited . Then i did sysctl -p. when i run ulimt -n i get 100000 . but when i do cat /proc/pid/limits i still see 32768.

Answer (score 0):

For processes managed by systemctl, please provide the limits in

> /etc/systemd/system/cassandra.service

You have to change

> LimitNOFILE=100000

and then perform

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload